# Printing heart spade diamond and tree symbols in scala

Tags: scala, unicode, printing

I have been trying to print all the cards symbols in scala ( both in eclipse & REPL ) . but when i print the unicode of these characters i get only the question mark symbol.

Here is my piece of code .

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")
println("\u2764")
```

Output of above code is just a ? .
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Works for me both in REPL and IDE. I suspect it might be an issue with your terminal settings.

Comment: Definitely repl to blame here. You could try writing to a file and then open the file to see its contents on a decent editor to confirm